# Form submit with radio in table has data in form_state['input'] and not in form_state['values']

Tags: forms

While developing a form for Drupal 7, I need a few radio groups, placed inside a table (one radio group per table row). The radios are defined as `'#type' => 'radio'` (not radios) and grouped together using the same name attribute per group. Nevertheless, when the form is submitted, the radio selections are not in the `$form_state['values']` array, but in `$form_state['input']`.

As you can see from the screenshots, all data is stored in `input`, with the radios being outside the `'undefined'` array, even though I placed them in `$form['undefined'][$key][x]`. In `values` only the select and textfield data is retained.

Any ideas? It's been two days now that I'm trying to resolve this :(
Thank you in advance.

```
function game_insert_form($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state, 'form_state');

  $test_data = array(
    '2' => 'Alfa',
    '4' => 'Beta',
    '6' => 'Gamma',
    '8' => 'Delta',
  );

  $header = array(
      t('Name'),
      array('data' => t('Existing'), 'colspan' => 2),
      array('data' => t('New'), 'colspan' => 2),
  );
  $form['undefined'] = array(
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#theme' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => array(),
  );
  foreach ($test_data as $key => $data) {
    // Label
    $label = array('#markup' => $data);
    $children = array(&$label);
    $row = array(array('data' => &$label));
    unset($label);
    // radio 0
    $radio0 = array(
      '#type' => 'radio',
      '#return_value' => 0,
      '#value' => 0,
      '#name' => 'undefined-' . $key . '-radio',
    );
    $children['radio0'] = &$radio0;
    $row[] = array('data' => &$radio0);
    // dropdown
    $select = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => array(0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One'),
      /*'#states' => array(
        'enabled' => array(
          ':input[name="undefined-' . $key . '-radio"]' => array('value' => 0),
        ),
        'required' => array(
          ':input[name="undefined-' . $key . '-radio"]' => array('value' => 0),
        ),
      ),*/
    );
    $children['select'] = &$select;
    $row[] = array('data' => &$select);
    // radio 1
    $radio1 = array(
      '#type' => 'radio',
      '#return_value' => 1,
      '#value' => 0,
      '#name' => 'undefined-' . $key . '-radio',
    );
    $children['radio1'] = &$radio1;
    $row[] = array('data' => &$radio1);
    // textfield
    $textfield = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#maxlength' => 40,
      '#size'=> 40,
    );
    $children['textfield'] = &$textfield;
    $row[] = array('data' => &$textfield);

    $form['undefined'][$key] = $children;
    $form['undefined']['#rows'][] = $row;
    unset($radio0);
    unset($select);
    unset($radio1);
    unset($textfield);
  }
  $form['next'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Test'),
    '#weight' => 0,
    '#name' => 'test',
  );
  return $form;
}

function game_insert_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state, 'submit: form_state');
}
```

[image: Initial selection]
[image: values after hitting the submit button (inside the submit function)]
[image: input after hitting the submit button (inside the submit function)]

Comment: I run into a similar issue myself and I have been wondering how you dealt with this. The only thing to be working so far is be using `$form_state['input']` to get back the values but don't know if it is correct and where exactly it happens.

Comment: @Wtower thanx for reminding me to post the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I managed to find the answer (after **a lot** of experimentation). The following code works fine for me. I am not sure if everything is needed, but I won't touch it as long as it works.

- Pay attetion that I use an associative array for the `#rows` array, in order to be able to find the correct row without keeping track of indexes.
- The most bizzare part is that I had to add `$form[$key]['#type'] = 'value';` to hold the selected value.
- The `'#name' => $key,` is obviously used to group the radios
  together per row.
- The `'#id' => drupal_html_id($key . '[' . $item . ']'),` was also
  added, but I'm not sure if it's needed.

Obviously one does not need to use a seperate column for the label, but I display it this way because in my code I use drop downs and other controls instead of the labels shown here.

Here is the code:

```
function game_test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state, 'form_state');
  $test_data = array(
    'alfa' => array(1, 2, 3),
    'beta' => array(1, 2, 3),
  );
  $header = array(
      t('Name'),
      array('data' => t('First'), 'colspan' => 2),
      array('data' => t('Second'), 'colspan' => 2),
      array('data' => t('Third'), 'colspan' => 2),
  );
  $form['undefined'] = array(
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => array(
      // The keys here are used later on for the correct #row insertion
      'alfa' => array('title' => t('Alfa')),
      'beta' => array('title' => t('Beta')),
    ),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="game_update_table">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  $table = &$form['undefined'];
  foreach ($test_data as $key => $data) {
    // This stores the value in the $form_state['values']. It must be outside the table.
    $form[$key]['#type'] = 'value';
    foreach($data as $item) {
      $element = array(
        '#type' => 'radio',
        // this value will be assigned to the $form_state['values'][$key]
        '#return_value' => $item,
        '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values'][$key]) ? $form_state['values'][$key] : 0,
        // Radio group stored in input[#name] with the selected radio's #return_value as value
        '#name' => $key,
        '#id' => drupal_html_id($key . '[' . $item . ']'),
      );
      // Attach the radio to the logical tree, so as to be included in $form_state['values']
      $table[$key][$item] = &$element;
      // Attach the radio to the render tree, so as to be rendered.
      $table['#rows'][$key][] = array('data' => &$element);
      unset($element);
      // Attach its label to the render tree, so as to be rendered.
      $table['#rows'][$key][] = array('data' => array('#markup' => 'Label ' . $item));
    }
  }
  $form['next'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Test'),
    '#weight' => 0,
    '#name' => 'test',
  );
  return $form;
}
function game_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state, 'submit: form_state');
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Wow, the "bizarre part" is a life saver! Thanks, it also applies to Drupal 8.